# Very strange __getattr__ behavior in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had an error in my code (similar to the error below) but the result seems very strange to me. Can someone explain to me how **getattr** is getting called with the name being "hello"?

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print name
        assert name != 'hello'
        return self.hello

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        class B(A):
            @property
            def hello(self_):
                return self.durp

        self.b = B()

c = C()
print c.b.bang
```

The output of this is:

```
bang
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print c.b.bang
  File "test.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    return self.hello
  File "test.py", line 4, in __getattr__
    assert name != 'hello'
AssertionError

shell returned 1
```

I understand of course that there is no durp property in C (this is the error I speak of). However, I would not expect `__getattr__` to be called with hello as the string. I feel like I'm not understanding something fundamental about the way `__getattr__` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called when accessing an attribute via "the usual methods" fails.  The way Python knows whether "the usual methods" have failed is that an AttributeError is raised.  It can't tell, though, whether this AttributeError was raised in trying to get the original attribute you were trying to get, or some other attribute accessed as part of that process.  So here's what happens:

1. Python tries to access `c.b.bang`
2. the b object has no attribute "bang" so the `__getattr__` is called.
3. the `__getattr__` tries to get `self.hello`
4. Python finds the attribute `hello`, whose value is a property
5. In trying to evaluate `self.hello`, Python runs the `hello` property.
6. Running the `hello` property tries to access a nonexistent attribute `durp`.  This raises an AttributeError
7. Because an AttributeError was raised as part of trying to evaluate `self.hello`, Python thinks there is no such attribute available via "the usual methods".  It therefore calls `__getattr__` with "hello" as the argument.

This behavior is confusing, but is basically an unavoidable side effect of how attribute lookup in Python works.  The only way to know that "normal attribute lookup didn't work" is that an AttributeError was raised.  There is [a Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1615) about this, which apparently people are still working on, but no real solution exists so far.

Comment: So basically the class C creates an AttributeError exception, since there's no __getattr__ in C it just bumps up w/o getting "stale" and A tries to handle it because there's an exception, even though it didn't originate in the A class, lame. Seems like an odd way to determine that "the usual methods" have failed, but that would certainly explain what's happening.

Comment: Hi. Can you add to your comment this code: http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2012/01/04/python-meta-programming-gotcha-with-getattr/ in simplified form? I would like to have single reference place which explains the issue (your comment) and shows minimal code example to reproduce the issue (link).

Comment: @WloHu: I don't think that's a great way to handle this.  If you want to have one place to look, you can create your own webpage with the info you want.  What I posted is an answer to the question that was asked, and I don't think it's a good idea to clutter the answer with a different example just because you found some other blog post that you want to be combined with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

`return self.hello` in the definition of `a.__getattr__`

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print name
        assert name != 'hello'
        return self.hello
```

triggers a new attribute search, this time with `'hello'` as the value of the `name` parameter, which causes your assertion to fail

Comment: If I didn't have the error in the hello property the assertion would never fail because __getattr__ would never get called with the "hello" string. Conceptually it shouldn't get called because the hello property exists, but as BrenBarn explained python is just a bit odd in how it handles the "usual methods failed" approach so class A tried to handle class C's non-existant property.

Comment: thanks for the correction in the comment, BrenBarn is correct